# Ruby rails - text field change event and ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok.. I am running into this types of issues more often. Most of my html is ajax rendered and I use fields and values from rendered page to make new ajax requests. But none of the events seem to fire. Need to understand this why is that.

This is a simple form with text field which I want to make ajax call on a change event, to skip the form/button. And it is not working. What do I change here?

```
<div><%= form_tag users_search_path, :remote => true, :id => 'search_form' do %>
<%= text_field_tag  :keyword, nil, :maxlength => 11, :size => 20 %># Tried this putting outside of this form, didn't work. 
<%= submit_tag " Search ", :id => "search_button", :onclick => "javascript:user_search()"%>
<% end %></div>
```

`<%= text_field_tag  :keyword, nil, :maxlength => 11, :size => 20 %>` Tried this putting outside of this form, didn't work.

```
$(function(){
$("#keyword").change(function() {
        alert('ok');
        $.post('/users/search', function(data) {
      $("#search").html(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Did the `$.post` fail? Was your callback not called? You do know that the [`<input>` has to lose focus before the change event is fired](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents), right?

Comment: @muistooshort - On the console I don't see post request coming in at all.

Comment: But what about your `alert` in the jQuery callback?

Comment: @muistooshort - I don't get that 'alert' either.

Comment: And what are you doing that would make you think a change event should be fired?

Comment: @muistooshort - Any input typed in the text field shall fire change event.

Comment: Incorrect, check the spec I linked to in my first comment.

Comment: @muistooshort - hmmmm - Then change or focus event does not trigger by typing text in the text area. I read through the list, but what does? Most of the examples I saw for auto-completing used change event on a text field.

Comment: A focus change will. Otherwise you're left with keydown, keyup, and keypress events and timers.

Comment: @muistooshort - But I am using jquery `change`.

Comment: Which is just a wrapper around the underlying DOM event. You can't use the change event for what you want to do, you'll have to do more work and use another type of event.

Answer (score 0):

Because the last jquery code is a function, it's not executed until you call it. Remove the first and last line, then it will be run when the page is loaded so it will attach the function defined inside to your text box.